# Loop listbox and pause in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox

I am trying to loop through listbox items and have a countdown and other code between each item but it just wont work - fully. It wont pause between the listbox items.

It should work like:

Get listbox item
get random number and put in label
run code using listbox item
count label down
repeat with next item

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick

    'loop each item to search
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        'code to run based on listbox1
        MsgBox(ListBox1.Items(i))



        'get time to wait
        Dim seconds As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split("-")

        Dim snum1 As Integer = seconds(0)
        Dim snum2 As Integer = seconds(seconds.Length - 1)
        Dim RandomClass2 As New Random()
        Dim RandomNumber2 As Integer

        If snum2 < snum1 Then
            snum2 = snum1
        End If

        RandomNumber2 = RandomClass2.Next(snum1, snum2)
        Label7.Text = RandomNumber2 & " seconds"

        ' MsgBox(RandomNumber2 & " seconds")
        timeLeft = RandomNumber2


        If timeLeft > 0 Then

            timeLeft -= 1
            Label7.Text = timeLeft & " seconds"
        Else
            Timer1.Stop()
            Label7.Text = "---"

        End If


    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont completely follow, but if you want `a countdown and other code between each item` then you shouldnt put the whole loop inside a Timer tick event. Sounds like the tick event should do one item with and index variable telling it which one to do this time.  I cant see that it is actually DOING anything with the Listbox other than looping as many times as there are items.  Anyway it wont pause between items because the processing loop is all inside the tick event.

Comment: I put  msgbox in place of the actual code working w/ the listbox item.

Comment: Probably still should start by moving the loop OUT of the timer tick if you want it to pause between list items (if that is what the timer does - provide the delay).